# How can I concatenate these two statements in SQL into one query?

Tags: sql

I want to get data from a database, filtering  for duplicate values between two dates. I'm using this code to get duplicate values:

```
SELECT emp_name, COUNT(emp_name) 
FROM tb_absencess 
GROUP BY emp_name 
HAVING COUNT(emp_name) > 1
```

and I'm using this code to select data between two dates:

```
SELECT emp_name, cbo_job, abss_date, abss_date_re, abss_no, cbo_type 
FROM tb_absencess
WHERE abss_date BETWEEN '" + abss_date.Text + "' AND '" + abss_date2.Text + "'
```

How can I combine the two statements into one query?

Comment: This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also: which columns do you want in the final results? Do you want to exclude the duplicates, or return only the duplicates? Do you want to also limit the duplicate employees to the date range? Sample data and results would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to put them in one query?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, but the requirements aren't clear:

```
SELECT emp_name,cbo_job,abss_date,abss_date_re,abss_no,cbo_type 
FROM tb_absencess
WHERE abss_date between @AbssDate1 and @AbssDate2 
   AND emp_name IN (
       Select emp_name  
       FROM tb_absencess 
       GROUP BY emp_name 
       HAVING COUNT(emp_name)>1 
   )
```

Comment: thank you for the replay :
I have benefited from your answer .